# Execute PHP Code from File On Other Computer

Tags: php

Is it possible, to include PHP code in a separate file on another computer. If so, how?

For example:

On the first computer:

```
#Host 1 Script
$username = "dfgd";
$password = "sdff";

#Code I need help with
```

And then on the second:

```
#Host 2 Script

#Code which needs to be run on Host 1 which will manipulate $username and $password
```

Obviously, I would not be able to store the script on Host 2 in a .php file because when it is read, nothing would print out... But is it possible?

Comment: While it's not impossible, it sounds like a Really Bad Idea™. What do you need this for?

Comment: I'm writing a script which would be distributed to users. Users would fill in the usernames and passwords and other configuration options and then the actual code would be run of my server.

Comment: Is the code you're talking about meant to _run_ on their computer, or do you want to run it on your server and then have the user's computer do something with the results?

Comment: @octern It's meant to run on their computer. I want the script to pull the code from my server and run it on their server.

Comment: In that case the code is nothing more than text. You could serve it over a regular http connection and have the script on their computer exec() it. That sounds like a security risk, though. If an attacker is able to direct them to a different site or tamper with the code they get from your site, the user's computer will then be executing arbitrary code with no restrictions.

Comment: what's the purpose of this convoluted approach, over 'normal'  code distribution method?

Comment: @Dagon 1) Lighter/smaller file to distribute. 2) "Over the air" updates. That way, if a bug or vulnerability is found, it's automatically updated without them having to do anything. 3) Simpler file: just enter username and password and save.

Comment: @MihirSingh  1)slower 2)greater security issues 3)Bandwith wasting. so I'll take the tried and true method thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as reading files over HTTP is enabled in the server, you can use `include*()` or `require*()` to read the file and execute the returned PHP. Simply tell the other system to not parse it in their PHP engine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to check how the soap works:
[soapclient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php), [soapserver](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php)